# SQLAlchemy & postgres - add days to date, get date diff and compare. Coerce error

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

No matter what I try I keep getting an error `cannot coerce the integer to in interval.`

```
@get_due_date.expression
def get_due_date(cls):
    return func.add(cls.date_last_service, cast(cls.get_service_schedule, INTERVAL), func.now()) <= 3.5
```

The equivalent python code for what I want to do is.

```
((self.date_last_service + timedelta(days=self.get_service_schedule)) - datetime.datetime.now()).days <= 3.5
```

Any one know why I'm getting this error? `cls.get_service_schedule` is an integer and you can cast a class

Answer (score -1):

According to the [document](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#the-uppercase-datatypes), UPPERCASE datatype represent an exact datatype. You need to make sure your database backend support that datatype.

<del>For example, these is no "INTERVAL" datatype in MySQL</del>

sqlalchemy cast function translate expression into `CAST` expression in sql, and `CAST integer AS INTERVAL` is invalid expression to postgres.

If you want an `INTERVAL` datatype, use `func.make_interval`[2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html) [3](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#table-values-table-and-column-valued-functions-row-and-tuple-objects)

Comment: Postgres does have an `interval` type: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html